# How to capture a filename with or without an extension

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm trying to capture and replace a filename like
000035 ZSMS_1.mp3
but also a file like
000035 1OMNA
(I'm basically trying to reorder them so they look like e.g., ZSMS_1(000035).mp3).
I've tried

```
^(\d+) (.*)(\..*$)?
^(\d+) (.*?)(\..*$)?
```

What I expect to happen:
000035 ZSMS_1.mp3:

```
[
  {
    "groups": [
        "000035",
        "ZSMS_1",
        ".mp3"
      ],
    "match": "000035 ZSMS_1.mp3"
  }
]
```

000035 1OMNA:

```
[
  {
    "groups": [
        "000035",
        "1OMNA",
        ""
      ],
    "match": "000035 1OMNA"
  }
]
```

What happens:
1.

```
^(\d+) (.*)(\..*$)?
```

000035 ZSMS_1.mp3:

```
[
  {
    "groups": [
        "000035",
        "ZSMS_1.mp3",
        ""
      ],
    "match": "000035 ZSMS_1.mp3"
  }
]
```

000035 1OMNA:

```
[
  {
    "groups": [
        "000035",
        "1OMNA",
        ""
      ],
    "match": "000035 1OMNA"
  }
]
```

2. 

```
^(\d+) (.*?)(\..*$)?
```

000035 ZSMS_1.mp3:

```
[
  {
    "groups": [
        "000035",
        "",
        ""
      ],
    "match": "000035 "
  }
]
```

000035 1OMNA:

```
[
  {
    "groups": [
        "000035",
        "",
        ""
      ],
    "match": "000035 "
  }
]
```

Comment: The second pattern works for your example data. You need `$2($1)$3` in the replacement. https://regex101.com/r/ynJ0ow/1

Comment: Oops, it was originally a typo, the actual pattern was ^(\d+) (.*?)(\..*$)? but putting $ at the end instead does work nicely. Thanks, didn't think to do that. :)

Comment: Just placing `$` at the end in `^(\d+) (.*?)(\..*$)?` [might not do what you need](https://regex101.com/r/FOPIo9/3) if the string contains several dots. My solution [will cope with that](https://regex101.com/r/FOPIo9/4).

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Wow, you're right. Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(\d+)\h+(.*?)(\.[^.]*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FOPIo9/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `\h+` - 1+ horizontal whitespaces (for better regex engine cross-compatibility, you may use `[^\S\r\n]+` or just `[ \t]+` to match a tab or space)
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: zero or more chars other than linebreak chars, as few as possible
- `(\.[^.]*)?` - an optional capturing group #3: a dot and then 0 or more chars other than `.` as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

You could try following regex:

```
^(\d+)\s*(?:(\w+)?)(?:(\.\w+)?)$
```

Details:

- `^` - start of line
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: matches a digit
- `\s*` - separates group 1 and 2
- `(?:(\w+)?)` - Group 2 (optional): matches any word character
- `(?:(\.\w+)?)` - Group 3 (optional): matches the character . and any word character
- `$` - end of line

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4WDY03/2/)